# Convert to join query

Tags: sql, join

```
select t.* from table1 t where t.id NOT IN(
select Id from t2 where usrId in
(select usrId from t3 where sId=value));
```

I the result i need is like if there are matching id's in t1 and t2 then those id's should be omitted and only the remaining rows should be given to me. I tried converting into join but it is giving me the result i wanted. Below is my join query.

```
SELECT t.* FROM table1 t JOIN table2 t2 ON t.Id <> t2.Id 
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.Id=t2.Id WHERE t3.sId= :value
```

This doesn't feth me the correct result. it was returning all the rows, but i want to restrict the result based on the matching id's in table t1 and table t2. Matching id's should be ommited from the result.I will be passing the value for sId.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: *Why* do you want to rewrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down and solve problem step by step.
So your query

```
select t.* from table1 t where t.id NOT IN(
select Id from t2 where usrId in
(select usrId from t3 where sId=value));
```

on converting the inner query to JOIN will yield

```
select t.* from table1 t where t.id NOT IN
(SELECT T2.ID FROM T2 JOIN T3 on T2.UsrID =T3.UsrID and T3.sID=value)
```

which on further converting to JOIN with outer table will be

```
select t.* from table1 t LEFT JOIN
(SELECT T2.ID FROM T2 JOIN T3 on T2.UsrID =T3.UsrID and T3.sID=value)t4
ON t.id =T4.ID
WHERE t4.ID is NULL
```

In case you completely want to remove sub-query you can try like this

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table1 t 
    LEFT JOIN T2
        ON T.ID=T2.ID
    LEFT JOIN T3
        ON T3.UsrId=T2.UsrID AND T3.sId=value
WHERE T3.UsrID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks to all for replying and both the queries are working perfectly fine. Can you do me one more favour, how can i write the same query using hibernate

Comment: @user3292629 I suggest that will be a different question and you should post it on SO as a different question under [SQL] and [hibernate] tags

Comment: i want the hibernate query for the same.

Comment: OK. I will post it as a different question.

Comment: @user3292629 Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Comment: The answer you posted without subquery didn't work for me. The one you posted first worked for me. Thanks @DhruvJoshi.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be an accurate refactor of your query using joins.  I don't know if we can do away with the subquery, but in any case the logic appears to be the same.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
left join
(
    select t2.Id
    from table2 t2
    inner join table3 t3
        on t2.usrId = t3.usrId
    where t3.sId = <value>
) t2
    on t1.Id = t2.Id
where t2.Id is null
```